# Rhodes : Error!!! Wrong Android API version

Tags: android, rake, rhodes

I just did un-installation of instant_rhodes-2.4.1.exe and install instant_rhodes-3.0.0.exe to Windows 7

Now when I

```
rhodes app HelloWorld 
cd HelloWorld 
rake run:android
```

it show me `Error!!! Wrong Android API version`

how do I correct this problem?

Comment: I try re-run the rhodes-setup but still not working, what else could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

refer to http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/browse_thread/thread/da61c4036cb7435b#

"***For the moment rhodes do not support Android 3.1 SDK (r12). Please download Android 3.0 SDK.***"